# How do I make my sliding panel close when the area outside it is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, responsive-design, panel

So I have this nice sliding navigation panel that appears when the screen is narrow enough. I'm pretty pleased with it so far, but I would like it to close when the user clicks/taps outside the panel. How would I modify my jQuery script to make that happen? (I am a jQuery novice)

Site: http://www.toprival.com/temp/side_menu/side_menu1.html

jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $panel = $("#panel");
    $tab = $("#tab");
    $menu_icon = $("#menu_icon");

    $tab.mousedown(function() {
        var currentPanelPosition = $panel.css("left");
        var newPanelPosition;

        if (currentPanelPosition === "0px") {
            newPanelPosition = "-200px";
            $menu_icon.css("background-position-y", "0px");
        } else {
            newPanelPosition = "0px";
            $menu_icon.css("background-position-y", "-40px");
        }

        $panel.animate({"left" : newPanelPosition}, 400, "easeOutExpo");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap your header and paragraphs in a div and then on click of that div trigger your menu to close.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="panel">...</div>
    <div id="content">
        <h1></h1>
        <p></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then in your javascript you can add:

```
$('#content').click(function(){
    if (currentPanelPosition === "0px") {
        $('#tab').trigger('mousedown');
    }
});
```

As a side note you should probably use 'click' rather than 'mousedown'.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a click listener to your wrapper.

```
$('#wrapper').on('click', function(e){
    $('#panel').animate({"left": "-200px"}, 400, "easeOutExpo");
});
```

The only issue you're going to have though, is that your panel is within that same wrapper div, so even when you click anywhere within the panel itself, the panel will close.

I think it'd be best for you to move the panel div outside of the wrapper, or as 'jdehlin' suggested, place your paragraphs etc. in a separate div, and attach the click listener to that instead.

Comment: Okay, getting there... now the problem is that clicking in the content area will _open_ the panel as well.

Comment: Dangit, why is my browser posting my comment every time I hit the return key now? I'm completely unable to post any code.

Comment: @KrisHunt I added an if statement to my answer which should solve your clicking in the content area problem.

Comment: Also, you can't put new lines in a comment, only a question or answer.

Comment: Oh, is there a difference between a comment and a reply?

Comment: Okay, in addition to your if statement, I also had to make the currentPanelPosition variable global so it could be accessed from outside the function, and then change the value of currentPanelPosition to match that of newPanelPosition each time the value of newPanelPosition is set. Works perfectly now. Thank you so much.